# Rewrite url in Nuxt for analytics purpose

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, analytics

I would like to use Plausible (or any other analytic tool) inside my **Nuxt** app.

However, most of them are blocked by adblocker. The documentation of Plausible explains how to rewrite url to avoid getting it blocked by adblocker using Next.js.

```
// next.config.ts
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
      return [
          {
              source: '/js/script.js',
              destination: 'https://plausible.io/js/script.js'
          },
          {
              source: '/api/event',
              destination: 'https://plausible.io/api/event'
          }
      ];
  },
}
```

I've tried to achieve the same with **Nuxt** using `routeRules` but it looks like it only allow you to perform redirect. That means Plausible url is still blocked by adblocker.

Is there a way to perform url rewrite using Nuxt to avoid analytics tools getting blocked like [Next.js rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites).

Thank you for your help.